# What this static variable function as expected in this recursive senerio?

Tags: c, recursion, static-variables

In my code below `variable1` is only being initialized to `0` in the very first call. My concern is that in every recursive call `static variable1;` is being declared. Will this cause problems with keeps track of the numbers? Or does the compiler know to skip over the declaration in each recursive call?

My code:

```
void funtion1(numberOfTimesCalled){
    numberOfTimesCalled++;

    static variable1;

    if(numberofTimesCalled = 0){
        variable1 = 0;
    }

    <some processing> 

    variable1= variable1+1;

    if(variable1<10){
        function1(numberOfTimesCalled);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're showing isn't valid C code. Also explaining the reason for using the static variable might help identify any further issues that you might be running into.

Comment: Note that this condition `if(numberofTimesCalled = 0){` is always false. It assigns the value `0` to `numberofTimesCalled` and the expression in`if` yields `0`. So the `if` condition will always be false. It's most likely a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern is that in every recursive call static variable1; is being
>   declared.

Yes, it's safe as a variable with *static storage duration* will not be re-declared again. It's lifetime is entire execution of the program and is initialized only once before. So unless you intend to "reset" the value of `varaible1`, you don't even need the special 
condition:

```
  if(numberofTimesCalled == 0){ // assuming you intended to check with ==, 
                                // a single = is for assignment.
        variable1 = 0;
    }
```

because a variable with static duration will be zero initialized at program startup.

Comment: That `if` statement needs help.

Comment: I just helped it with a comment ;)